# Where are the sources of the original curses library?

Tags: history, programming

The [curses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) is a terminal control library for Unix-like systems used in text based user interface applications. It has been used in many games in the past. It was developed by Ken Arnold and originally released with BSD Unix.

Where can I find the sources of the curses library (either as part of a Unix distribution release or the original sources as published by the author or some other official source)? Sources with history (in a version control system) would be even better.

I can only find sources for successors like ncurses or pcurses. Neither the [Wikipedia page of curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)), nor the overview page at [rocketaware.com](http://www.rocketaware.com/uint/curses/) resulted in something usable and searches for "freebsd libcurses" or "debian libcurses" all point to ncurses, not the original curses. The library is probably not in use anymore, but I would still like to study the original source code.

Comment: Hope the question is on-topic.

Comment: It is, although it might have as well great chances to find an answer on [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) - due being in their turf in the first place.

Comment: @Raffzahn and it would likely have received the same answer from the same user ;-)

Comment: @StephenKitt Don't doubt that at all :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The sources of early versions of curses are available in [Diomidis Spinellis’ Unix history repo](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/), for example [the 4.4BSD version of `libcurses`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/tree/BSD-4_4/usr/src/lib/libcurses). This includes [reconstructed history](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/commits/BSD-4_4/usr/src/lib/libcurses/), all the way back to [this synthetic 4BSD-era commit](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/commit/ec004506cbb94393fe5e9918d4227a943df41b49#diff-e91ff99720dcbf9b8713a0074a28cb350cd04655fb3344513c025104411fd5ad).

The sources are available in a number of other places such as [TUHS](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.4BSD/usr/src/lib/libcurses) (which has [a 2.9BSD version](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=2.9BSD/usr/src/lib/curses/) as well, along with the AT&T versions) but the above is the most convenient I know of for exploration, especially to see the evolution of the codebase.

Comment: Many thanks. This is more than I expected and can be used to retrieve historical information about many other libraries.